# When do Sanji's half of the crew board Big Mom's ship for the first time?

Tags: one-piece

In [Chapter 795](http://mangapark.me/manga/one-piece/s3/c795), we jump from Dressrosa to the aftermath of Sanji's side boarding Big Mom's ship.

What chapters did this happen? It's not specifically listed in the Manga Story Arcs in the arcs up to and including the [Dressrosa Saga](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Story_Arcs#Dressrosa_Saga).

**Edit:** Revoked the correct answer because I have a new doubt. In Chapter 807, Usopp says that the last time he spoke with the Sanji half of the crew was when they evaded Big Mom's ship, meaning they had a chance to speak after evading Big Mom but before meeting on Zou. Thus, it couldn't have been skipped, because the whole crew, or at least Usopp, was there with them.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That segment was never shown and was used specifically to prequel what is coming.

Similar cases have occurred in the anime but are usually filled in with filler. The story follows Luffy so when other characters go off and do their own thing away from him the manga doesn't reflect it.

With respect to the Edit: During the Dressrosa arc Usopp was one of the strawhats who stayed behind. IIRC there was an episode that had a cameo of sanji speaking to Usopp before things got too crazyin Dressrosa. It was when the coliseum event was still going on. We didn't see how the evasion happened but we did see that the ship was approaching. It wasn't brought up again until the Zou arc.

Comment: I have edited your answer with a link to a chapter that has a flashback to the events relevant to this question.

Comment: @MaxLi I have edited my answer taking your edit into account